# How can I convert a list in R into a raster?

Tags: r, list, r-raster

I want to convert a list I have to a raster in order to allow me to extract data at specific locations.

```
#create example data
tmintest=array(1:100, c(30,189,420))

#create example list
Variable <- list(Varname="Tmin")
Data = tmintest
xyCoords <- list(x = seq(-40.37,64.37,length.out=420), y = seq(25.37,72.37,length.out=189))
Dates <- list(start = seq(as.Date("2036-01-01"), as.Date("2065-01-01"), by="years"), end=seq(as.Date("2036-12-31"), as.Date("2065-12-31"), by="years"))
All <- list(Variable = Variable, Data=Data, xyCoords=xyCoords,Dates=Dates)
```

I see from the raster documentation that it doesn't accept lists, so I tried unlisting `All`

```
unlistAll<-unlist(All)
raster(unlistAll)
```

which returned:

```
Error in .local(.Object, ...)
```

So, I'm going to create it from scratch using the information from the list above:

```
myraster<-raster(nrows=108, ncols=21, xmn=-40.375, xmx=64.375,ymn=25.375,ymx=72.375,vals=All$Data)
```

but I got the error:

```
Error in setValues(r, vals) : values must be a vector
```

Am I going about this the wrong way? I just want to extract data from my list or raster for specific x/y coordinates.

Comment: You might want a `rasterBrick` rather than a simple raster, as you have the third data dimension. `brick(All$Data)` works without a problem, and you can probably use the other list elements to set the extent, etc.  See the documentation for `brick`.

Comment: @AndrewGustar Thanks, your suggestion was very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the extent:

```
xy <- cbind(x=rep(x, length(y)), rep(y, each=length(x)))
r <- rasterFromXYZ(xy)
```

Create a RasterBrick and set the extent

```
b <- brick(tmintest)
extent(b) <- extent(r)
```

How did you get these values? If you read them from a ncdf file, you could just to `brick(filename)`

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. The data are calculated indices, so not derived directly from a netcdf. Great to know you can do that though!